# Tamper voice using audiorecord

Tags: android

I am recording my voice using **`AudioRecord`** class and I am playing it with a small delay using **`AudioTrack`**

How can I change what my voice sounds like?

Comment: Drink too much beer.  It works for me.  (Sorry, couldn't resist).  How about speech to text then text to speech?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SoundPool class:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html

for example, using the `setRate (int streamID, float rate)` method, you can change the rate at which sound is played back. If you increase the rate, you'll sound like a chipmunk :-)